# Only some of my parse object update (Always 9 but no more) when I run this javascript parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getPicks", function(request,response){
var picks = new Parse.Query("Picks");
var num=0;
picks.find({
    success: function(results)
    {
        if ( results.length == 0 )
        {
            // No picks in databade
            response.success("No picks are live");
        }
        else
        {
            for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++){
                result=results[i];
                result.set("winningTeam",3);
                result.save();
                num++;
            }
            response.success("Found "+results.length+" pick objects!"+" num is "+num);
        }
    },
    error: function(error) {
        response.error("Query failed. Error = " + error.message);
    }
});
});
```

Im trying to update all of these pick objects to set their winning team to "3", I want to do something with every object in the database (i'll do that after i have this straightened out) then set the "winningTeam" field to 3. It works OK but for some reason if I have say.. 20 objects in the database, only 9 of them get updated when I run this code, if I have 50 objects, 9 get updated, if I have 9 or less they all get updated, kinda confused as to why. I'm new to parse cloud and to javascript so I'm probably just doing something stupid or not saving them right idk, but it finds all of the objects, but only updates some of them.

Comment: What's the value of `results.length` and `num` for a larger (10+ objects) query?

Comment: It gives the correct value, IE 20 object query returns 20 for both of them, which is why I'm confused. It finds all of the objects, but only changed 9 of them, could I be saving it wrong in such a way that the changes stop saving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try waiting for all the `save()` calls to return before calling `response.success()`:

```
// find your picks
picks.find()
// when it finishes
.then(function(results) {
  // build an array with a promise for each save call
  var savePromises = results.map(function(result) {
    return result.save({winningTeam: 3});
  });
  // and wait for all of them to finish
  return Parse.Promise.when(savePromises);
}).then(function() {
  // if everything went ok
  response.success();
}, function(err) {
  // if something bad happened
  response.error(err);
});
```

Comment: A bit lost on how your code works, brand new to JS and parse, but I'll see if I can figure it out and get back to you, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I'll add some comments to make it easy. It would be great for you to take a look on how promise works though

Comment: Will do, I'm guessing it's just in the parse javascript api somewhere? I'll go check it out.

Comment: Could you explain why you have 

return result.save({winningTeam: 3}); in brackets? I thought parse i'd have to do a object.set("Objectname", value); then save it? is this a shortcut or something?

Comment: Exactly, it's a shortcut for `obj.set('winningTeam', 3); obj.save()`